# Ant design collapse panel remains open after state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I have an issue with ant design collapse which I can't get through. I have a list of offers in a state array. For each item I created dynamically a panel. If we open this panel it contains a button. When the button is clicked I remove the specific item from my state. Until this point works fine, the state is updated and the panel items are rendered without containing the deleted one.

But here comes the problem: if we click the delete button on a panel which has other following panels after its, the following panel will be opened too even though it is closed. The state updates but the collapse's active key remains the same for some reason.

The question: How can I update the active key too if an item is removed? Thank you.

My Code:

```
const [RecievedOffers, setRecievedOffers] = useState([])

const renderRecievedOffers = (Offers) => Offers.map((offer, index) => {
<Panel header={'Test'} key={index}>
       ..some other things
       <Button shape="circle" icon={<MinusOutlined />} size="medium" onClick={() => handleRecievedOfferDecline(offer.OfferID)} />
</Panel>
}

const handleRecievedOfferDecline = async (offerId) => {
  let newRecievedOffers = RecievedOffers.filter( (offer) => offer.OfferID !== offerId)
  setRecievedOffers([...newRecievedOffers])
}

return (
 <Collapse accordion>
 {renderRecievedOffers(RecievedOffers)}
</Collapse>)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because of the map's `index` being used as the key for the list of panels. This might cause issues with list's state when they order of items changes, as it does in your case. It's not recommended to use indexes for keys as mentioned and explained in [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys).

Since you're mapping over the `offer` objects, you can use their `OfferID` as keys for the list, which should solve your problem.